# SQL Inner Join then left Join 3 tables

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012, left-join, inner-join

This is using SQL Server 2012.

I want to use inner join and left Join with 3 tables.

Plan is:

- take a list of rows from table S ,
- corresponds to table V by s.pid=v.pid and v.pro='p' and s.reg='u' which v.categoryid=8
- then, there is a processed log (table L),
- corresponds to table V by L.pid=v.pid and L.pro=v.pro

I want to find the set which is no existed in table L, means no processed before.

I wrote:

```
select top 100 
    s.* 
from   
    S
inner join 
    V on s.pid = v.pid
left join 
    L on L.pid = v.pid and L.pro = v.pid
where 
    s.reg = 'u'
    and v.pro = 'p'
    and v.categoryid = 8 
    and L.pid is null
    and L.pro = 'p'
```

This returns nothing...

Please help

Comment: `SELECT TOP...` - is this SQL Server? I'd suggest adding the appropriate db technology tag.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox might be MsSQL. thought i am not sure `top` exist, but I would assume the OP knows is SQL a bit.

Comment: @Sebastien - in MySQL it's `SELECT ... LIMIT X` at the end of the query.

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox Yeah... corrected the mistake afterward, but this is standard MSSQL.`SELECT... LIMIT x` do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `left join` a table and then filter it's columns to equal not null values, it will in effect filter out the `null` values on that table, including the cases where a join was not made.

You will need to handle the null values to prevent this from happening. for example, you would change

```
and L.pro='p'
```

to

```
and (L.pro IS NULL OR L.pro='p')
```

or more simply

```
and ISNULL(L.pro, 'p') = 'p'
```

Comment: you are right! if i just remove " and L.pro='p' " it works! thanks